# Selected columns that are not in group by

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am a quetions about SQL. For example i have a table like this

```
Name    Surname Price   Adress
john    smith   100     adress123
alex    martin  200     adress2
john    smith   300     adress123
```

And i want to group this records which name is same.And this records prices must be sum()
Generally i write query like this

```
SELECT SUM(PRICE),NAME AS TOTAL_PRICE  FROM TABLE1 A GROUP BY A.NAME
```

But when i want to select other columns i should be group by like this

```
... group by A.NAME,A.SURNAME,A.ADRESS
```

I want select this columns without group by. I want to ask what is the best way selecting other columsn without using group by condition?

I am waiting this result

```
200 ALEX    MARTIN adress2
210 JOHN    SMITH  adress123
```

but i don't want to group by surname and adress column

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results that you are trying to achieve.  The question immediately arises:  what values do you use for the other columns?  Typically, they would have more than one value.

Comment: Have you considered what would happen if 2 different rows had `John Smith` and `John Doe`? What would you expect your results to be then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an arbitrary value from the rest of the columns by using `MIN()` or `MAX()`:

```
select sum(price) as total_price, name, max(surname) as surname,
        max(address) as address
from table1 a
group by a.name;
```

Comment: i am especially ask which is running more performence ?  which one we use ?